# Did the Japanese Spider-Man ever have a TV crossover with any other Super Sentai characters?

Tags: marvel, tv, spider-man

The main reason I'm asking this is because I plan to start watching the Japanese Spider-Man with my fiancee, and while doing research, I found that there was apparently another Marvel inspired Super Sentai show, *Battle Fever J*, partially inspired by Captain America.

Also, I saw that on the Wikipedia for *Kamen Rider*, there is an episode titled *"The Mysterious Spider-Man."*

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [The Mysterious Spider Man](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7xse0s) is a humanoid spider. :)

Comment: Ok, any other information? If you have any more info, I would gladly accept an answer

Comment: Truthfully, that's all that I know, that it's a "spider man" there, not "Spider-Man". I'll see if I come up with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, as I posted above, the episode you note, "[The Mysterious Spider Man](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7xse0s)", involves Kamen Rider fighting a spider man rather than Spider-Man. However, [*Kamen Rider V3 vs Spider-Man*](https://tokusatsu.fandom.com/wiki/Kamen_Rider_V3_vs._Spider-Man) is an actual crossover comic from the two TOEI series.

[image: Front cover of Kamen Rider V3 vs Spider-Man]

[image: One of the pages of the issue]

Prior to that, he showed up in *Spider-Verse #6*, which isn't really a cross-over.

Answer (score 1):

Likely predating the *Kamen Rider V3* crossover, there is a [*Battle Fever J*](https://ssentaiw.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Fever_J) [stage show](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Fever_J_Stage_Show_at_3_Heroes_Korakuen_Yuenchi) at [Korakuen Amusement Park](http://tokyowithkids.com/entertainment/korakuen_amusementpark.html), which has Kamen Rider Stronger, Japanese Spider-Man, Ultraman Jonias, and Doraemon show up to help Battle Fever J out.

[image: Image showing Ultraman Jonias, Japanese Spider-Man, Kamen Rider Stronger, and Doraemon posing with Battle Fever J]

*Battle Fever J* aired between 1979 to 1980, but I haven't found when the stage show started (or if there was a time when Japanese Spider-Man was added).

Comment: With Ultraman Jonias being introduced in 1980, that dates this show to around that date or later (the other shows predating that). [This collection of commercials starting in 1983](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6oPksH9M2M) don't seem to feature this stage show, so I'm guessing that it probably operated somewhere in the 1980-1982 time period.