# When was the Battle Fever J Stage Show at 3 Heroes Korakuen Yuenchi presented?

Tags: spider-man, doraemon, tokusatsu

In the course of providing an answer to [Did the Japanese Spider-Man ever have a TV crossover with any other Super Sentai characters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240604/did-the-japanese-spider-man-ever-have-a-tv-crossover-with-any-other-super-sentai), I found that there was a stage show which involved the "Japanese Spider-Man" crossing over with *Battle Fever J* (as well as with Kamen Rider, Ultraman, and Doraemon), [*Battle Fever J Stage Show at 3 Heroes Korakuen Yuenchi*](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Fever_J_Stage_Show_at_3_Heroes_Korakuen_Yuenchi). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a ton of information about it, other than this promotional photo showing the actors posing together.

[image: Promotional image showing Battle Fever J, "Japanese Spiderman", Ultraman Joneus, Doraemon, and Kamen Rider Harder posing together]

The newest character depicted in this image is Ultraman Joneus, who debuted in 1980 (or maybe 1979 as per the comment below). A [selection of commercials between 1983 and 1994](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6oPksH9M2M) for the Korakuen amusement park show a number of bits from the stage shows, but I don't see anything with *Battle Fever J* (although I do see some of the other Kamen Riders and at one point, a poster with a cartoon representation of Doraemon pops up). That suggests this probably ran in some period between 1980 to 1983 (because I doubt they would've had a later show featuring characters that were cutting edge a decade earlier).

So, when did this stage show take place?

Comment: According to [this](https://ultra.fandom.com/wiki/Birth_of_a_New_Hero), Ultraman Joneus debuted in April 1979, so perhaps this show could've taken place later in the same year.

Comment: Huh, so I guess that does expand the range.